# Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\React\react' error with React import correct

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am getting the below error on a page that is stopping it being rendered and after checking other similar errors I have double checked the import is correct and the node_modules react  index file is installed.

What else could be causing this? I have had linting issues yesterday out of nowhere that I thought had fixed themselves.

The file this refers to should be node_modules/React/react.indexjs but on my system is node_modules/react.index.js. I haven't changed this myself so i'm not sure where it has come from. I have also removed any code that was added to this file which could of been causing it.

```
Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\React\react'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might not help but have you tried to run npm install to make sure everything is installed properly?

Comment: I tried this but the error comes up straightaway.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 13):

This happens when you import react like this

```
import React from "React"
```

notice the capital `R`

instead, you should do :

```
import React from "react"
```

( with a small `r` )

Comment: Yes I have tried changing it around a few times and still the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

This happens due to case sensitivity. Check if the file name is exactly the same in the **same** case.

Eg:

```
Cannot find file: 'CheckBox.js'
```

Check if the filename is exactly **CheckBox.js** not Check**b**ox.js

Answer (score 1):

1.**diveLogTable.component.js** instead, you should do **DiveLogTable.Component.js** OR **DiveLogTable.js**.

2.Ensure you have imported React in all the files that have jsx. Like, import React from 'react' It might also be required by your build system that files with jsx have **.jsx** or **.tsx** extensions (not just **.js** / **.ts**).

3.Ensure that file names that are referenced in your code are matching actual file names in a filesystem. There could be issues if file names had changes in **capitalization**. Keeping file names in **lowercase** might be a good idea to avoid such sort of problems.

Answer (score 0):

try creating the index.js in the src folder, i'm sure you created it outside the src folder.